# Birt Report Parameter as WHERE-Clause

Tags: sql-server, birt

I have a BIRT-Report in which I want to show a certain amount of data (Hi Capt. Obvious). So far so good. Now the data lies within a MSSQL database and I'm connecting to it with a jdbc driver, this all works perfectly.

The problem is now that I want to pass a "query" Report parameter to this report. I know how to pass parameters to a report in the following fashion:
Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ?
```

And then you define the parameter in the Dataset-Parameters.

Now what I want to do is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table ?
```

Where my parameter contains something like

```
WHERE field1 = 'xyz' AND field2 = 2
```

The problem is that BIRT automatically adds a single quote in the beginning and in the end of every String-Parameter so that the final query looks so:

```
SELECT * FROM table 'WHERE field1 = 'xyz' AND field2 = 2'
```

This leads to MSSQL not being able to handle the query for obvious reasons.
How can you fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to code your query as `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ? and field2 = ?` ? (It is possible to code your query as desired using dynamic sql, but this will open up your code to the risk of SQL injection attacks - see http://xkcd.com/327/ .)

Answer (score 1):

With regards to SQL injection risk you can write:

```
this.queryText = 'SELECT * FROM table ' + params['where_clause'].value;
```

in the `beforeOpen` Data Set script.

But I highly recommend to avoid this construction and rewrite query to a form proposed by Mark Bannister, unless you are 100% sure that input is safe.